# How do I check to see if there are any roles that are not assigned to any users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been working on a bot that assigns roles to members based on what game they are playing, so that all members that are currently playing a game can be mentioned. I want to delete any roles that match the criteria and have no members. Can I do something like:

```
guild.roles.filter(r => r.members.size === 0 && r.name.startsWith('playing'));
```

Comment: Whats preventing you from running the code and seeing for your self?

Comment: Nothing, but that bit of code doesn't seem to do as I'd expected it. I ran it and I didn't get the result I'd wanted. Testing with logging indicated that the code wasn't doing what I needed.

Comment: So what was the code doing?

Comment: It doesn't seem to return the correct role when filtering by the size, as if r.members.size doesn't have a value.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? Should it have a value? (You just need to keep asking your self these kinds of questions. Eventually you will find what you're doing wrong)

Comment: Try logging each value of the roles you get back. What is their `members` value, what is the `.size` of said `members` value, what is the name of each role. Try to pin down where the problem occurs